# Combining results of two different tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to combine two tables with different sets of columns by a 'salesperson' column.
The problem with the query I've got so far is that some salespeople names are duplicated, and some from the right table are missing.

Transactions table

```
salesperson,     Profit,     Units
John             100          1
John             50           1
Carl             200          2
Matt             300          3
```

Connections table

```
salesperson,       Amount       
Carl               100
Lynda              200
Lucy               300
```

Combined table

```
salesperson,       (Amount+Profit),    Units(sum)
Carl               300                 2
John               150                 2
Matt               300                 3
Lynda              200                 0
Lucy               300                 0
```

This is what I've got so far

```
SELECT t.salesperson, SUM(t.profit) + SUM(c.amount), SUM(t.units)
FROM transactions AS t
FULL OUTER JOIN connections as c ON t.salesperson = c.salesperson
GROUP BY t.salesperson
ORDER BY t.salesperson ASC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT salesperson, SUM(total), SUM(Units)
FROM 
     (
        SELECT salesperson, Amount as total, Units
        FROM Transactions
        UNION ALL
        SELECT salesperson, Profit as total, 0 as Units
        FROM Connections
    ) T
GROUP BY salesperson
```

Comment: Wow, completely forgot about unions. Good solution.